# Add Data From One Table To Another Table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a tableview with genre: rock, rap, dance, country, pop, etc.

Lets say I have another tableView where I can make a custom list with a bunch of these genres.

Say in the mainView, I can add lists, like Dinner, Gym, Studying etc.  Then within each of these lists (when you click its cell it will push to a subtableview for that list).  I want to choose items from the separate genres to add to this subview.  Examplple, Dinner list might include country and classical music, and gym list might have rock and rap etc.

I have everything set up so far except the code that lets me add genres to the custom sub groups.  So I can make groups such as Dinner but I need to still make code that lets me fill this group with genres from the other tableView.

I think I need to have a modal view pop up when I click the add button.  THis model view will have the genre table and when I click a cell, the modal view will dismiss and it will add whatever I clicked as a cell in the group.

Comment: So what's your question?  If it's "will this work", code it up and try it.

Comment: Well I have the modal view and everything set up.  My question is, how can I make it so the modal view shows that genreTable and when I click on an item, it dismisses the modal view and adds that item to the current table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same genre array that backs the genre tables as the data source for the modal table.
In the modal table didSelectRowWIthIndexPath, get the genre string from that array.
Now you have lots of choices for how to get the genre item back to your detail table view controller.
You could post a notification, you could use a KeyValue Observer, you could pass a reference to the detail VC to the modal and then the modal can set an exposed attribute on the detail VC, etc.
Then the detail vc would add that genre value to whatever array is back it's data, and then you call reloadData on the detail VC table.
Your modal VC would have to do something like [navigationController popViewController:animated] to dismiss itself.

Comment: Thanks Mike I'm going to play around with the many options.  The Genre Array is stored in a .plist but everything else, such as the array/tableView the data will be added to will be all done using Core Data.

Comment: Another thing, I have added a uiview to the modal view, but if I want another sub table do I have to make a new class for it?  With my regular tableviews I usually have a separate class for each subtable, should I do the modal view the same way?

Comment: Hard to say without see the code.  You don't HAVE TO, you can do it all programmatically in one controller, but if the separate class pattern works for you, go for it.  Understandable code is only slightly less important than working code.